# Getting 404 error when retrieving items through Layout API

Tags: jss

I'm working with the React JSS Basic example. I created a new item based on the default "Welcome" component and I'm trying to retrieve it through JSS.

Here is my Sitecore tree :

[image: Sitecore tree]

To get Welcome-1 item (default one) I use this url : http://my-first-jss-app/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey=xxx&tracking=false

I try to get Welcome-2 item with different urls but it results in a 404 error.
Some urls that I tried :

- http://my-first-jss-app/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/home/welcome-2&sc_apikey=xxx&tracking=false
- http://my-first-jss-app/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/welcome-2&sc_apikey=xxx&tracking=false

I already read the layout service documentation that says the path must be “The path to the item, relative to the context site's home item”. This is the case in my urls but it doesn't work.

So I have two questions:

- Why my url to display Welcome-2 item is not correct ?
- Why Welcome-1 item is displayed when I reach “item=/” ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`item=/` returns the page item `/sitecore/content/my-first-jss-app/Home`, not the `Welcome-1` data source item. `Welcome-1` and `Welcome-2` are only items containing data, but no layout or presentation.

`Welcome-1` item data is displayed when you reach `item=/` because this item is configured in the data source field of the Welcome rendering that is present in the presentation details of the Home item.

Comment: @JohnB The Layout Service only retrieves items which have Sitecore Layout on them. Your structure seems odd, Welcome-1 and Welcome-2 should perhaps be child items of Welcome, and then you can configure the Rendering to return child items as well.